# New User: Help with Fonts in Overleaf Template

Tags: fonts, fontspec, installing-fonts

I found this nice template in Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/isw-student-thesis/xjwkfntnwrwc)
Can someone help changing the font? Please!

Garamond for Body and
Helvetica for Headings

Comment: Have you seen https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/font_typefaces ?  Is your question about changing the font in general, or having one font for the body and another in headings?  It would help if you [edit] relevant information into your question.  I don't know that this is really specific to Overleaf though.

Comment: This is specific to the template in Overleaf.
I saw this one (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/font_typefaces) but it looks way too complicated to change the font styles (Garamond for body and Helvetica for headings) inside the template and I end up with a lot of errors. Can you help?

Comment: "a lot of errors" is too vague, people don't like following links that may not survive, and a template is a lot to look through.  Could you post here what you think is the closest to what you want to achieve, but without any unnecessary packages and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile using `pdflatex`, you have to go to `iswthesis.sty` and exchange lines 89–95

from

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{osf,sc}{mathpazo}%
\RequirePackage{mathpazo} % Palatino with real small caps and old style figures
\usepackage{tgheros}
\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
\PassOptionsToPackage{scaled=0.85}{DejaVuSansMon}%
\RequirePackage{tgpagella}% bera monospace font
\RequirePackage{textcomp}% declare missing symbols
```

to

```latex
% \PassOptionsToPackage{osf,sc}{mathpazo}%
\RequirePackage{ebgaramond-maths}
% \RequirePackage{mathpazo} % Palatino with real small caps and old style figures
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
% \PassOptionsToPackage{scaled=0.85}{DejaVuSansMon}%
\RequirePackage{tgpagella}% bera monospace font
\RequirePackage{textcomp}% declare missing symbols
```

For `lualatex` you need to have a look at lines 101–103:

```latex
    \setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
    \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
```

Here you need to insert your system fonts:
`\setsansfont{Helvetica Neue}` or the version of Helvetica you've got installed in your system and
`\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{EB Garamond}` for Garamond.

Recompile and you're done!

Comment: You are an awesome human being! Thank you. 
The first method worked

Comment: Glad I could help. Now go and write an awesome thesis!